# How do I convert my SQL SERVER data into a SAS Table?

Tags: sql-server, data-mining, sas

I am using Enterprise Miner 6.2 and want to create a data source but my option is a SAS Table.  How do I go about exporting SQL Server or Excel data into a SAS table?

Answer (score 0):

SAS has many ways of connecting to and/or reading data from disparate sources. I haven't used Enterprise Miner, so I'm not sure which of SAS' methods are available to you directly from within EM, but it's likely there will be someone at your site who has some interface to Base SAS and who can help you/advise what data access products are installed and how you can use them.

For SQL Server data, SAS/Access to SQL Server or SAS/Access to OLE DB will allow you to read directly from SQL Server tables in place. Alternatively, someone could provide you with a dump of the data you need from the SQL Server database.

For Excel data, there are also SAS/Access products, but SAS also has native capabilities to read in the data if saved as, for example, a .csv or .txt file.

To help answer you further, perhaps can you come back with some details about what SAS products/interfaces are available to you?